# Repeating code execution while mouse button is down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('.test').click(function(){
$('.act').removeClass('act');
$(this).addClass('act');
});

$('#btn').mousedown(function(){
$('.act').insertBefore($('.act').prev());
});
```

```css
.test{
cursor:pointer;
}

.act{
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>323</div>
<div class='test'>525</div>
<div class='test'>727</div>
<div class='test'>929</div>
<div class='test act'>453</div>
<br>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Keeping the button pressed I need to continue `act` to be moved to the top, without clicking again, and again.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval` on `mousedown` then `clearInterval` on `mouseup`:

```js
$('.test').click(function(){
$('.act').removeClass('act');
$(this).addClass('act');
});

var intervalId;
$('#btn').mousedown(function(){
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        $('.act').insertBefore($('.act').prev());
    }, 500);
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

```css
.test{
cursor:pointer;
}

.act{
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>323</div>
<div class='test'>525</div>
<div class='test'>727</div>
<div class='test'>929</div>
<div class='test act'>453</div>
<br>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#btn').mousedown(function () {
        var currentIdx = $(".act").index();
        while (currentIdx != 0) {
            $('.act').insertBefore($('.act').prev());
            currentIdx = $(".act").index();
        }
    });
```

Comment: that's too fast. `act` is on top in a moment. Need time to control where to stop.